# Getting the nth highest value row in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

My problem sounds simple enough but I havent been able to find a solution that works. 
I need to get the row with say 5th highest value of an attribute with sqlite.. Entries are random of course. So its not sorted.
I did find a few solutions with sql but apparently not all sql functionalities are supported by sqlite.

Thanks in advance

Comment: An example using SQL that is not strictly SQLite compatible but expresses what you're trying to accomplish would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove duplicates, use DISTINCT.
To get only the fifth value, use the OFFSET clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SomeAttribute
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY 1 DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4
```

Comment: Thanks man... You really saved me a lot of work.. This answer worked perfectly.. You wont believe how complicated queries people suggested to do the same in sql.

Comment: Just curious...do we really need 'DISTINCT' clause when we already LIMIT at 1?

Comment: @pahariayogi DISTINCT is applied before LIMIT. It ensures that in a table "1,2,3,3,4,5,5,6", the returned value is 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try the **'Limit'** keyword.

The query below will eliminate the first four rows by using 'not in'.
Then the last 'Limit 1' will select the 5th row.

Select * from Programs 
Where ProgramId not in 
(Select ProgramId From Programs order by programId limit 4 )
order by programId Limit 1

EDIT:

To add in CV's 'Distinct' and 'OFFSET' suggestions, the finished query would look something like...

```
Select StudentName From Students Where Marks in (
Select distinct Marks from Students Order By Marks desc Limit 1 offset 4)
```

Comment: Your answer would work if the attribute values were unique.. The case that I have does not have unique values. For eg... In a table student with attributes marks ,many students could have the same marks. If asked who scored the 4th highest we would have to consider people with same marks too.